# Rails Globalize2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, multilingual, globalize2

How can i implement multiple language translation fields in one form with globalize2?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but this module seems to do just that:

http://github.com/alvarezrilla/batch_translations

(found it in globalize2's README, under 'Related Solutions' - stackoverflow won't allow me to post another link :P)